# In Spyder IDE, how can I change the font size of rendered mathematical equations in the help window?

Tags: spyder

Are there any ways to change the font size of rendered mathematical equations in the help window?

I actually do not have this problem when I run Spyder in my Ubuntu server, however the font size of rendered mathematical equations in the help window looks too large on my local Windows PC.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229267/spyder-change-size-math-equations) was already asked without answers.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Too big font size of rendered mathematical equations]

Comment: What's your Spyder version?

Comment: It's 3.3.6 - both on my local Windows PC, and my Ubuntu server. Python version is 3.7.6 for my PC and 3.7.5 for my server.

Comment: However, downgrading Python version for my PC from 3.7.6 to 3.7.5 was not helping.

Comment: This is fixed in Spyder 4.

Comment: Thank you so much. Updating to Spyder 4 did help. However, I usually hit Ctrl + I in front of the function to see the documentation on the help window, and it works well on the console, but not on the editor. In short, the documentation does not pop-up on the help window, when I hit Ctrl+I in the editor. Do I have to install Kite for solve this problem for Spyder 4?

Comment: OK, I've found the same issue here, which I could find the appropriate solution - deleting ~/.spyder-py3: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5393.

Comment: However, how can I disable the Kite working in Spyder 4? It seems to be integrated in Spyder 4 for default, but there seems to be no disable check-boxes in the preferences. When using Kite help, hitting tab key on the function, it shows no examples, which is different from the default Spyder 4 help.

Comment: To deactivate Kite you can go to `Preferences > Completion and linting > Advanced` and uncheck the option called `Enable Kite`.